# How to populate table based on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which contains some data about car makes.

It looks like this:
   [image]

Now in the table appears data for all makes, but I need to show data only for the make that I've clicked. For example if I click on Audi to show data only for this make.

This is my view where I have populated the table:

```
<div class="row">
    @{var testList = Model.ProductMatchingVehicles.GroupBy(p => p.Make.Name).ToList(); foreach (var item in testList) {
    <div class="btn btn-danger btnMake" data-id="@item.Key" id=btnMake onclick="myFunction()">@item.Key</div>
    } }
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Make</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Engine</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.ProductMatchingVehicles != null) { foreach (var item in Model.ProductMatchingVehicles) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Make.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Model.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Engine.Name</td>
                </tr>
                } }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you please advise me how to achieve this in javascript or jquery? Thanks!

Comment: Filter the car data so that the container only contains the selected brand (array.filter), then rerender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following code:

1) Modify `<tbody>` as follows:

```
<tbody>
    @if (Model.ProductMatchingVehicles != null) { foreach (var item in Model.ProductMatchingVehicles) {
    <tr class="vehicle_rows" data-refId="@item.Key">
        <td>@item.Make.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Model.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Engine.Name</td>
    </tr>
    } }
</tbody>
```

Here we have added the `class` and `data-refId` attribute to each `<tr>`

2) Modify the button click function a bit:

```
<div class="btn btn-danger btnMake" data-id="@item.Key" id=btnMake onclick="myFunction(this)">@item.Key</div>
```

Here passing `this` reference to function

3) The function `myFunction` will have logic something like this:

```
function myFunction(obj){
    var $button = $(obj);
    var car_make = $button.data("id"); //reading the data-id of clicked button

    //hide all rows first
    $(".vehicle_rows").hide();

    //show only currenly clicked buttons associated rows
    $(".vehicle_rows[data-refId="+car_make+"]").show();
}
```

Comment: Can I have a last question? :) How can I avoid to not show the entire list when I firstly enter on the tab (this list is it on a tab). I tried this way, but it not works:  $("#tabMatchingVehicles").click(function () {
            alert(@ViewBag.FirstMake);
            $(".vehicle_rows[data-refId=" + @ViewBag.FirstMake + "]").show();
        }); After I enter on the tab and I start clicking on the buttons it works perfectly.

Comment: in your try if you are getting the `alert(@ViewBag.FirstMake);` on opening the tab; then just add one more statement `$(".vehicle_rows").hide();` before `.show(` call.